# what's the difference in usage of the nasai, te and plain imperative forms?

Tags: usage

As far as I understand (correct me if I'm wrong), there are 3 ways to turn a japanese verb, the plain form which usually adds an "e", the te form and the nasai form. When do you have to use each one?